# Google team drive and google colaboratory downloading/uploading files

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

So I have google Team drive set-up with all the permissions.
1. How I can access google team drive in google colaboratory? I think i'm missing something... it's always showing me output of my drive
2. I want to download all the "data" from google team drive to my google colab notebook is it possible to make it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with 'Team Drive', but if I understand the structure of Drive well, my guess would be it'd work the same way it does with 'My Drive'.

That being said, I think the easiest way you could do this is by

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/drive")
```

This will generate a link, click on it and sign in using Google OAuth, paste the key in the colab cell and you're connected.

Check out the list of available files in the side bar on the left side and copy the path of the file you want to access. Read it as you would, with any other file.